# Is it possible to open a ljpg (lossless jpeg) file in Python?

Tags: python, image, jpeg, octave, spyder

Does anyone know if it is possible to open a ljpg (lossless jpeg) file in Python? (specifically I'm using spyder on Windows XP).

I've searched around on Google, here and the Python documentation and I can't see anything.

If it's not possible, I'll try to work out how to call Octave to convert it, but it would be great if I didn't have to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the below didn't work, try this wrapper:
http://ebiznisz.hu/python-jpegtran/

Appears to do the trick.

---

http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.image-module.html
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Any of the two should be able to.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("test.ljpg")
im.show()
```

---

Comment: Thanks for that! PIL doesn't recognise it, but I'm just installing pyglet to see what that can do.

Comment: Hmm - Unfortunately, pyglet isn't doing it either. This is the Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Projects\MV_QA_program\Las Vegas Images\LasVegasAnalysis.py", line 15, in <module>
    jpgfile = image.load("LA2_15x15_6MV.ljpg")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 197, in load
    raise first_exception 
pyglet.image.codecs.ImageDecodeException: GDI+ cannot load 'LA2_15x15_6MV.ljpg'

Comment: Try the wrapper linked above.. appears as if this codec is not a general codec yet (and i'm not suprised, using `ljpeg` contra `png` isn't bringing anything new to the table so it's discareded and `png` is refered in it's place for convenience and perhaps performance)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I have had a lot of trouble making that (using cygwin) though. I solved problems with 'INT32', but I'm stuck on errors like this >>>>>>>
rdswitch.o:rdswitch.c:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `_imp__jpeg_add_quant_table'  <<<<<<< I'm going to give the Octave route a go.

Comment: jpegtran is a native binary for linux and should be able for you in a binary form (even through cygwin): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/jpegtran.1.html